# ios5 - Using Facebook for login view

Tags: facebook, ios5, authentication

I am working on an application where I have to use facebook for authentication and then after successfull authentication, i want to allow the user to continue with the app.

I am seeking some help on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow your users to use your app with Facebook, you have to register it on Facebook (see 'Create New App' [here](https://developers.facebook.com/apps)).

This will allocate your app a secret code and an ID code, that you can use with either the iOS, JavaScript or PHP APIs to complete the authentication process.

See here for more details:
https://developers.facebook.com/ios/ (if you're building a native iOS app)
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/mobile/web/ (if you're building a web app and packaging it for iOS)

Comment: Then it will be a 2 step process. Isn't it?

Comment: No. The user only has to authorize your app once. Then, when the user tries to log in to your app (using the [FB.login](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method), one of two things will happen. Either:
a) If the user is logged in, the authentication process will happen automatically; or
b) The user will be prompted to log in to Facebook, before your app authenticates.